# error al reproducir audio seleccionado

Tags: java, android, audio, mediaplayer

Estoy intentando hacer una pequeña app para practicar que consta de una actividad de inicio y una actividad para seleccionar un audio y reproducirlo.
Para seleccionar el audio utilizo:

```
btnCambiarAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select     Audio "), COD_SONIDO);
        }
```

En el **onActivityResult**:

```
case COD_SONIDO:
                Uri mUri=data.getData();
                String stringUriAudio= data.getDataString();
                //String stringUriAudio= mUri.toString();
 SharedPreferences datosGuardados = getSharedPreferences("datosMarcos",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = datosGuardados.edit();
                editor.putString(nombreAudioMarco, data.getDataString());
                editor.apply();
```

He probado también con la instrucción comentada. Como veis, recibo la ruta del audio seleccionado y la almaceno mediante **SharePreferences**.

Después mediante otro botón reproduzco el audio seleccionado.

```
SharedPreferences datosGuardados = getSharedPreferences("datosMarcos",MODE_PRIVATE);

            //obtiene la ruta guardada del archivo de audio seleccionado y vinculada al marco.
            String audioMarco = datosGuardados.getString(nombreAudioMarco, "NULL");
                    Uri uriAudio= Uri.parse(audioMarco);
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext,uriAudio);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "fallo en la reproduccion");
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no hay archivo de audio vinculado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Primero recupero la ruta del audio seleccionado en string guardada con **SharedPreferences**, después creo un **Uri**, y la uso para reproducir el audio con **MediaPlayer**.

En principio funciona, es decir, de la actividad de inicio paso a la actividad de selección, selecciono un audio, y cuando le doy al play, funciona, reproduce el audio sin problemas y lo paro también sin problemas.

El problema, y lo que no entiendo, y llevo días buscando y probando, es que si salgo de la actividad de selección a la de inicio, y vuelvo a la actividad de selección, ya no funciona, da este error:

> D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player

Y si vuelvo a seleccionar el audio y lo reproduzco, vuelve a funcionar.

En principio, si la ruta almacenada en el sharedpreferences, funciona después de seleccionar el audio, debería de funcionar cuando salgo y regreso a la actividad.

Creo que puede ser algo de permiso, pero el audio que selecciono está en la memoria interna, y en teoría no necesita darle ningún permiso especial.

Como información, añadir, que las pruebas las realizo en un dispositivo fisico, un sony m2, con **lollipop (v 5.1.1)**.

Gracias.

Comment: Pablo agrega por favor un ejemplo de Uri que tratas de carga.

Comment: Hola. Lo siento pero no se a que te refieres exactamente. El Uri lo cargo pasándole como parámetro el string con la ruta del audio que almacené en el SharedPreferences, y después paso ese Uri como parámetro al mediaplayer para reproducirlo.

Comment: Hola @PABLOMILLAN obten el valor de la variable "uriAudio", la cual contiene la uri del medio a reproducir.

Comment: Hola, primero gracias por la ayuda y el interés. Pero no se a que te refieres, la variable uriAudio la creo yo usando el String audioMarco, y es la que uso como parámetro para reproducir. Y el caso es que funciona, el problema es cuando salgo de la actividad y vuelvo a ella. He intentado pasar el string directamente como parámetro al mediaplayer, pero me da error siempre.

Comment: Entendido @PABLOMILLAN, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Por si ha alguien le sirve, he conseguido solucionar el error.

Haciendo pruebas vi que en dispositivos mas viejos que tengo por casa si que me funcionaba, y a partir de ahí encontré la solución. Si lo he entendido bien, el error lo da a partir de android 4.4(kitkat), y para solucionarlo hay que sustituir el ACTION_GET_CONTENT por ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, y así mantiene el permiso URI que da al documento cuando se selecciona, ya que con ACTION_GET_CONTENT no mantenía el permiso, por eso no daba error cuando reproducía el audio al seleccionarlo y si daba error cuando salía y volvía a entrar en la actividad.

Pero con este cambio solo mantiene el permiso si no se reiniciar el dispositivo. Para consiguir mantener el permiso aunque se reinicie el dispositivo hay que añadir en el onActivityResult:

```
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
        & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.
Este es el enlace a la documentación de android que lo explica:
[permisos persistentes.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el valor que se recibe en el intent que contiene el audio puede estar vacio, por lo tanto se estaría guardando este valor y no funcionaría correctamente, te sugiero validar este caso usando este método:

```
   public static boolean isNullorEmpty(String s ) {
        return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();
    }
```

Al detectar que se tiene valor vacio se tomaría el de la preferencia

```
   String audioMarco = datosGuardados.getString(nombreAudioMarco, "NULL");
```

tu código sería:

```
case COD_SONIDO:
            Uri mUri=data.getData();
            String stringUriAudio= data.getDataString();

            //*Si el valor no es null o vacio guarda el uri. 
            if(!isNullorEmpty(isNullorEmpty)){
                SharedPreferences datosGuardados = getSharedPreferences("datosMarcos",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = datosGuardados.edit();
                editor.putString(nombreAudioMarco, data.getDataString());
                editor.apply();
             }
             ...
             ...
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, es verdad, añadiré el código para comprobar que no es nulo para evitar errores, pero el problema en este caso creo que no es este, ya que añadí una salida por consola para ver la ruta que guardaba al seleccionar el audio, y otra salida por consola para ver la ruta que leía antes de reproducir el audio para confirmar que hay ruta guardada y leída, y que ambas coinciden. También me ayudó a comprobar que la ruta leida es correcta cuando falla la reproduccion

Comment: (perdón, pero no me dejó editar de nuevo. Continuo con el comentario).  También me ayudó a comprobar que la ruta leida es correcta cuando falla la reproduccion, por lo que entiendo que no es problema del parámetro que recibe. Gracias